# Can I use multiple whiles within a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, nested-loops

```
while (...) 
{
    while (...)  
    {   ......
    }

    while (...) 
    {   ......
    }

    while (...) 
    {   ......
    }
}
```

Can I write my code this way?

Can I use multiple `while`s within a `while` loop in C language?

(I don't have my laptop with me right now so I can't test it out myself.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why don't you just try it yourself? There is no limit for the usage of loops.

Comment: The simple answer is YES.You can test it in Ideone.Its an online compiler and IDE .

Comment: @bub "Try it yourself" is a dangerous philosophy in C... Besides, saying there's "no limit" kinda defeats the purpose of the section of the C standard entitled ["5.2.4.1 Translation Limits"](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.2.4.1), doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. But be careful with performance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure you can. Give it a go:-).

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  while (i < 10) {
    while (j < i) {
      printf("%d\n", j);
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

It is not a very useful program. Just to illustrate the principle.

Comment: This was meant in an encouraging manner. The author is on the right track. If they try this out on their laptop, they will find it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Loops in general are highly versatile; you can nest them however you want. However, without getting into multi-threading, only one loop can be executed at a time.

Your code will execute the first sub-loop until it's condition is satisfied, then it will do the second one, then the third one, then if the main loop is still true, it will go back to the first one etc. It will NOT do all three simultaneously.

Comment: I can use them *however I want*, eh? I'm not sure about that... Does that mean that I decide what is valid and isn't valid in the world of C?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. You can NEST them howver you want.